# Passing data to BTsidemenu

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have developed an application in which I am using this:  [BTSimpleSideMenu](https://github.com/balram3429/BTSimpleSideMenu)

In my app I am passing cell `label's` through this:

```
-(void)show{
    sideMenu.delegate = self;
int count;
    count = [rssOutputData count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        NSString *items = [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:i]xmltitle];    
BTSimpleMenuItem *item = [[BTSimpleMenuItem alloc]initWithTitle:[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:i]xmltitle] image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]
                                                               onCompletion:^(BOOL success, BTSimpleMenuItem *item) {
                                                                   catLbl.text = [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:i]xmltitle];
                                                               }];
        sideMenu = [[BTSimpleSideMenu alloc]initWithItem:@[item] addToViewController:self];

    }
    [sideMenu toggleMenu];
}
```

In this code `[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:i]xmltitle]` is actually the data which I am parsing from an XML file. I have a total of 5 entries in it that I want to show in the side menu, but unfortunately through this way the menu is only showing the last entry and only a single row.

I know this might be because it is overwriting entries on the first cell.

Please view the link given above and please help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will solve your problem your are creating BtSimplemenuitem and BTSimplesidemmenu in every iteration so it will make a lot of sidemenu just change your code to this will work

```
-(void)show
{
sideMenu.delegate = self;
int count;
NSMutableArray *itemsArry = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
count = [rssOutputData count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    NSString *items = [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:i]xmltitle];
    BTSimpleMenuItem *item = [[BTSimpleMenuItem alloc]initWithTitle:[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:i]xmltitle] image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]
                                                       onCompletion:^(BOOL success, BTSimpleMenuItem *item) {
                                                           catLbl.text = [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:i]xmltitle];
                                                       }];

    [itemsArry addObject:item];
}
NSArray *itemSarry=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:itemsArry];
sideMenu = [[BTSimpleSideMenu alloc]initWithItem:itemSarry addToViewController:self];
[sideMenu toggleMenu];
}
```